# Service object has no attribute process error using Selenium with Google colab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to follow along a youtube video for using Selenium for webscraping and I'm getting a attribute error service object has no attribute process. I believe it might be a path issue within colab. I uploaded chromedriver.exe inside the sample data folder and copied path. No sure what I'm missing please help. I've commented out other attempts. The error is pointing at driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

```
    from selenium import webdriver 
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    #from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    PATH = "/content/sample_data/chromedriver.exe"
    #service = Service(r'/content/sample_data/chromedriver.exe')
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(PATH))
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome(service)
    driver.get("https://login.virtualracingschool.com/?email_error=&form_error=&password_error=")
```

Answer (score 0):

##### `.exe`. files are specific to Windows, and can't run in UNIX systems.

Google-Colab uses Ubuntu 20.04 currently, meaning you'll need the compilled chromedriver for this specific OS. See [comment](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles/issues/10#issuecomment-1387618009) for a example **installation script** for **Google-Colab**.